# Problems printing predictions using tensorflow.js

Tags: web, predict, tensorflow.js, mobilenet

I have retrained a mobilenet_v2 model using the [make_image_classifier](https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/tree/master/tensorflow_hub/tools/make_image_classifier) command line tool to retrain the model and the [tfjs-converter](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/tree/master/tfjs-converter) to prepare the model for the browser.

```
make_image_classifier \
  --image_dir image_data \
  --tfhub_module https://tfhub.dev/google/tf2-preview/mobilenet_v2/feature_vector/4 \
  --saved_model_dir trained_models/1 \
  --labels_output_file class_labels.txt \
  --tflite_output_file trained_model.tflite
```

```
tensorflowjs_converter \
    --input_format=tf_saved_model \
    --output_format=tfjs_graph_model \
    --signature_name=serving_default \
    --saved_model_tags=serve \
    ./trained_models/1 \
    ./web_model
```

For testing the TF Lite model I used the [tflite example code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/examples/python/label_image.py).
I followed the instructions of the tools and hence used the code provided.

If I now try to predict an image in the browser I don't get the expected output. It looks like only the probabilities are getting printed without the labels.

```
const MODEL_URL = 'model/model.json';
const model = await tf.loadGraphModel(MODEL_URL);

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");;
const img = canvas.getImageData(0,0, 224,224)

const tfImg = tf.browser.fromPixels(img).expandDims(0);
const smalImg = tf.image.resizeBilinear(tfImg, [224, 224]);

let result = await model.predict(smalImg);

console.log(result.print())
```

output: Tensor
     [[0.0022475, 0.0040588, 0.0220788, 0.0032885, 0.000126, 0.0030831, 0.8462179, 0.1188994],]

Testing the model with python works well and I got the expected ouput with labels and probabilities. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Could you please add to the question the python code and how your are converting the model to js ?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have added links to the tools / instructions I used. Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the python code there is the following after the predition :

```py
  # output_data is the predition result
  results = np.squeeze(output_data)
  top_k = results.argsort()[-5:][::-1]
  labels = load_labels(args.label_file)
  for i in top_k:
    if floating_model:
      print('{:08.6f}: {}'.format(float(results[i]), labels[i]))
    else:
      print('{:08.6f}: {}'.format(float(results[i] / 255.0), labels[i]))
```

The same processing needs to be done after the prediction in js. The array of `labels` contains all the labels of the dataset. It needs to be loaded in js as it was loaded in the python code from the `labels.txt` file.

```js
const topkIndices = result.topk(5) 
const topkIndices = await topk.indices.data();
const categories = (Array.from(topkIndices)).map((p: number) => labels[p]);

const topkValues = await topk.values.data()
const data = Array.from(topkValues).map(p => p * 100);
// categories will contain the top5 labels and
// data will contain their corresponding probabilities
```